# What band does Mike Milligan and the Kitchen Brothers refer to?

Tags: prog-rock

In the TV series *Fargo*'s episode *The Myth of Sisyphus* (S02E03), officer Lou Solverson meets Mike Milligan and the Kitchen Brothers and they have [these lines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH13hE4zmmQ):

> LOU: You wouldn't, by any chance, be **Mike Milligan and the Kitchen Brothers**, would you?
>   MIKE: You make it sound like a prog rock band. "Ladies and gentlemen, introducing **Mike Milligan and the Kitchen Brothers**."

I like rock prog, but I don't remember listening to a band with a similar name. Does this name refer to a particular band, or maybe a mix of several band names?

The action takes place in 1979 so the showrunners are probably refering to bands that predate this time.

Comment: TBH, I can't think of anything LESS like a stereotypical prog-rock band name than MM and the KB. Getting subjective here, I realise, but to me the name suggests a generic bar band or band reviving an old style like jugband or trad jazz. I don't recall a band from the initial prog-rock era with a name anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chambers Brothers were a well-known band from that general time period that fit the "[X] Brothers" format.  They are generally classified as psychedelic, but can arguably be considered early forerunners of prog.

"[X] and the [Y]" is a long-standing standard way of naming a band that has a separate identity than the lead singer.  But there's no well-known prog rock band called "[X] and the [Y] Brothers."

I suspect the show wanted to make a "rock band name" joke, and threw in the modifier "prog" as a misguided attempt at period authenticity.

Comment: I can think of Allman Brothers Band, also from this time area, but still not prog rock.